# Show error : valid email address in magento

Tags: php, validation, email, checkout, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8. I am new to magento, so on the checkout page, when I enter the email address, it shows a popup with " enter valid email address".

Again when I enter the email id and password in already registered column, it works.

What is the problem and where I should find the email validation file in magento ?

And how to validate the email id?

[image]

I am using this code

```
  <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="billing:email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this-        >__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="<?php       echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email    Address') ?>" class="string input-block-level input-text validate-email required-entry billing-email" />
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

validation of email id:

```
    "validate-emails": [
        function(value) {
            if ($.mage.isEmpty(value)) {
                return true;
            }
            var valid_regexp = /^[a-z0-9\._-]{1,30}@([a-z0-9_-]{1,30}\.){1,5}[a-z]{2,4}$/i,
                emails = value.split(/[\s\n\,]+/g);
            for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
                if (!valid_regexp.test(emails[i].strip())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does that "validate-email" class trigger any validation? Can you post the code of that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i post the validation of email id.

Comment: I checked the regular expression and it works to me. Are you sure that validation is triggered? Can you debug it?

Comment: no, actually i don't know how to debug it

Comment: Try following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474245/how-to-debug-magento-application and post the trace, to see if the function is accessed.

Comment: nothing error show after debug, can you tell me where we have to validate the email for guest login?

Comment: Since the validation could be client-side, can you a staging url where I can debug it for you (this way we are going anywhere)?

Answer (score 0):

You are blaming the wrong piece of code for the validation of email: the alert that pops up is from the code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#onepage-guest-register-button" ).click(function(){
       var mailid=jQuery('#guest-email').attr('value');
       var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
       if( !emailReg.test(mailid) ){
          alert("please Enter valid Email Address")
          return false;
       }else if (jQuery('#guest-email').attr('value')==''){
          alert("please enter valid Email Address ");
          return false;
       }else{
          var mailid=jQuery('#guest-email').attr('value');
          jQuery('.bill-mail').val(mailid);
          checkout.setMethod();
       }  
    })
  })
</script>
```

While your generated input is:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="guest-email" name="guest[username]" value="">
```

I debugged and it seems that the problem is with the else-if statement:

```
  else if(jQuery('#guest-email').attr('value')=='')
```

Try with:

```
 else if(jQuery('#guest-email').val()=='')
```

Comment: can you please tell me in which file is this script, because i am unable to find this.

Comment: This is beyond my possibilities, since I'm inspecting only the generated source. I've found it inside the source of page http://54.169.49.64/littlebees/index.php/checkout/onepage/. You should be able to search inside your code, using some keyphrase like "please Enter valid Email Address" or something like that.