# magento upgrade to 1.9 results to category/product page terminating unexpectedly

Tags: php, magento

I've just completed an upgrade of Magento from 1.5 to 1.9 following the command line guide at http://blog.chapagain.com.np/update-upgrade-magento-1-x-to-latest-version-via-both-browser-command-line/

along the way, some errors were encountered but eventually were all resolved through SO.

However, after the upgrade, with the index recreated and cache cleared, the category page and product page are no longer displaying the products, checking the HTML source sees that the HTML is being cut off after rendering the menu.

There are no errors being logged. All other pages are working fine, the products can be found and displayed through the search function.

Changing to another theme does not solve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your admin-settings are set to [enable error-logging](https://www.magestore.com/magento-basic-setting/how-to-enable-error-and-exception-logging-in-magento), and here is a more in-depth look at [enabling error-printing in PHP/on a server level](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/33071)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have double checked the configuration and ensure that error logging is enabled. I've also introduced errors into the layout to verify that exceptions are really being logged.  However, the category / product page is still cut off without any errors logged.

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved by enabling debug following [How to debug magento application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474245/how-to-debug-magento-application)

main cause was the Config.xml in app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/etc is still the old version. replaced it with the version from app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc solved the issue.